# Derivation of Flow Rate and Pressure Drop Relationships

Tags: fluid-dynamics, bernoulli-equation, navier-stokes

In fluid mechanics, I consistently see two different types of expressions relating internal flow and pressure drop:

$$ \Delta P = \frac{k}{2} \frac{\rho}{A^2} Q^2
$$

which is based on Bernoulli's equation, and is the basis for most orifice flow equations, Major and Minor loss coefficients ($k$), etc.

Then there is the Poiseuille equation for laminar pipe flow:

$$ \Delta P = \frac{8 \mu L}{\pi R^4} Q
$$

which for duct of unknown geometry whose flow resistance is measured empirically can produce:

$$ \Delta P = \lambda \mu Q $$ or simply $$ \Delta P = \lambda Q  
$$

These result in a $Q$ and $Q^2$ dependence of pressure drop on flow.

I was trying to identify exactly where these relationships come from and what their range of validity is.  My guess is they follow from the the velocity terms in the steady, incompressible Navier-Stokes equation:

$$ \nabla  P = -\rho (\textbf u \cdot \nabla) \textbf u + \mu \nabla ^2 \textbf u
$$

which for 1 dimension I believe would reduce to:

$$ dP = -\rho u \, du + \mu \, d^2u
$$

But the calculus got a little beyond me at this point.  For instance: I've reduced the 3 dimensional gradients to $dP$, $du$ and $d^2 u$, but should it really be $\frac{dP}{dx}$, $\frac{du}{dx}$ and $\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}$ ?  Then if I try to integrate this equation, it seems like the first $u$ term gets integrated once to $u^2$, and the second Poiseuille term ends up as proportional to $du$, needing to be integrated again.  So I got stuck there.

As far as the validity of the simpler expressions (Bernoulli and Poiseuille), I imagine the true behavior is the sum of both terms, but at low Reynolds number (high $\mu$) the Poiseuille term dominates, while for high Reynolds or inviscid flows, the Bernoulli term dominates?

Was hoping someone could tell me if I am on the right track, and help me get to the finish line on the derivation.  My goal is to have a solid rationale and understanding for when to use either expression in practice.

Note: Throughout, $\rho$ = Density, $Q$ = Volumetric Flow Rate, $A$ = Cross Sectional Area, $R$ = duct radius, $\mu$ = dynamic viscosity, $P$ = pressure, $u$ = velocity, $k, \lambda$ = constants.

Comment: The Bernoulli equation is based on inviscid flow, while Posseuille flow is a solution of the full NS equation, so they have a different theoretical basis. If you set $\mu=0$ then you can integrate the NS equation along a streamlined streamline to get the Bernoulli equation

Comment: I suppose my implied goal is to integrate the 1D NS equation above to have an analytical solution with both terms, for cases where both may be significant (For the case of 1D steady ducted flow). Is this possible to do?  Would it have to be discretized and solved numerically?

Comment: If it is a constant cross sectional area, the inertial term doesn't come in.