# Derivation of flow rate and pressure drop

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow, bernoulli-equation, navier-stokes

I just read an expression relating to internal flow and pressure drop from here ([Derivation of Flow Rate and Pressure Drop Relationships](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/720658/)).
I am curious about how to derive this formula.

[image]

Comment: What about when viscous forces dominate?  An example is Poiseuille flow in a pipe.

Answer (score 1):

That was my question. Friction losses are usually characterized in terms of dynamic pressure:

$$ \Delta P = k \frac{1}{2} \rho u^2 
$$
($ \Delta P$ pressure drop, $ \rho$ density, $u$ average flow velocity)
Where $k$ is a constant that is specific to the obstruction, often empirically derived, typically on the order of $\text 1$.

I recast velocity $u=Q/A$ in terms of volumetric flow rate $Q$ and cross sectional area $A$, which in practical applications are normally the more accessible quantities.

The dynamic pressure expression is ultimately derived from Bernoulli's equation, which expresses conservation of energy along a fluid streamline:

$$\Delta P = \frac{1}{2} \rho u^2 + \rho gz + (\mathrm {loss \, terms})
$$

This balance basically boils down to:

$$\begin{pmatrix}\text {Energy per fluid volume}\\ \text {at a given point}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\text {Kinetic}\\ \text {Energy}\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}\text {Gravitational}\\ \text {Energy}\end{pmatrix} +
\begin{pmatrix}\text {Losses due to}\\ \text {Friction, etc.}\end{pmatrix}
$$
Without gravity, it reduces to the dynamic pressure expression, with each loss term cast in the form of the first equation I listed.

Comment: Do you really need that scrolled `\text` block? Can't you just use `>` to quote it instead? Or just use plain text without any special markdown or mathjax features?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.May I know if this equation can be applied for the Turbulent flow?if not,if there are some equations can be related to flow rate,cross section area,and pressure drop for Turbulent flow?thanks!

Comment: Yes, in fact the $k/2 \rho u^2$ formula probably works better in turbulent regimes than laminar because it neglects viscous behavior where $\Delta P \propto u$.  In turbulent flows the Darcy Weissbach eqn might be helpful. And for a straight pipe section $k=fL/D$ you get $f$ from a Moody Chart